# Javascript function does not wait for the callback function to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an online platform for which I want every `HTML` form submitted by users to be digitally signed using Digital Signature Token.

I am testing an `API(Javscript API + .exe (that need to be installed at the users' machine)).`

The code goes like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sign Form Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="docsign.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var DocSignObj = _docSignObj; 

    var myCallbackFun;

    $(function(){ 

        //This lets the API know that SignData() function needs to call 
        //myCallbackFun function after its job is done
        DocSignObj._initialize(myCallbackFun);      

    }); 

   function sign(form){

       //does some stuff like serializing form data etc
       var formData =serialize(form);

       //This function is exposed by the API.
       //It opens the dialog box to  get Digital Certificate Details from 
       //user, 
       //validates the details and 
       //then generates the Digital Signature which is returned in the 
       //callback 
       //function
       DocSignObj.SignData(formData);       
   }

   function submitForm(){   

       //Once this function is called it should wait till myCallbackFun does 
       //its job.
       sign(form);

       //The following line of code is executed immediately instead leaving 
       //DIG_SIG element as empty
       document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit(); 
  }

  function myCallbackFun(result){
        var digitalSignature = result.sig;
       document.getElementById("DIG_SIG").value = digitalSignature;
   }
</script>

<form id="FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED" action="" method="">

    <input type="hidden" id ="DIG_SIG" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="data" /></br> 
    <input type="submit"
        value="Sign Form Data" onclick="submitForm()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is that the

```
document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit();
```

line executes immediately after the

```
sign(form);
```

and the form gets submitted without signing.

Comment: You don't need to call `submit()` again on your form from within `submitForm`, just `return true`

Comment: Is `DocSignObj.SignData(formData);` asynchronous?  If so does it return a Promise or have a callback mechanism you can use to tell your code to wait until it's finished?

Comment: @DanielBeck This method is exposed by the API. I have no idea about the internal working expect the fact that is call a callback function whose name I have to pass while initialzation as     
    DocSignObj._initialize(myCallbackFun);

Comment: @RobM. Elaborate please

Comment: **Move** `document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit(); ` inside `myCallbackFun(result)` (which is your callback function). Also, don't you need to check the `result` data before submitting the form? Also, return false inside `submitForm()` method.

Comment: You are already submitting the form - clicking a submit button does that without any javascript. If you `return true` you will not prevent the default event handling and the form will be submitted. If you are trying to intercept the submit process, you should add an `onsubmit` handler to the form, rather than the submit button

Comment: @JanardhanMaithil can you provide the library documentation for docsign.js so we can view it's API or if that's your custom lib can you provide us the API for `document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit()` and `DocSignObj.SignData()` it appears when you call `sign(from)` when it hits the line `DocSignObj.SignData(formData);` it will do a network call of sorts or run a timeout function in which case JS thread will run the rest of `submitForm()` you'll need to edit the method `sign(form)` to return the promise and inside a `.then()` method have `document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit();`

Comment: @skobaljic `myCallbackFun(result)` is common for all forms . Also the `document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit();` this piece of code may vary to a hundred lines

Comment: @Andrei 'DocSignObj.SignData` calls an  ActiveX object which opens a pop up for user to select its Digital Certificate.It then signs the form data and calls the callback method `myCallbackFun(result)`

Comment: @JanardhanMaithil hopefully it's a promise try this for your `sign(from)` method change `DocSignObj.SignData(formData);` to `reutrn DocSignObj.SignData(formData);` and inside `submitForm()` change `sign(form)` to `sign(form).then(function(data) { document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit(); });` if this works it means that the method is a promise

Comment: without seeing any real documentation we won't be able to give you a better answer

Comment: lastly horrible solution / hack but you can create a global variable `var specialFormCase = false` then inside of `myCallbackFun(result)` you can do a check `if (specialFormCase) {document.FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED.submit(); specialFormCase = false}` and remove it from the `submitForm` function again it'll work just not a lovely solution you'll need to set `specialFormCase = true` at the start of `submitForm()` before calling `sign(form);`

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of errors among passing some undefined `form` to `sign( form )`, serializing a form without using `name=""` for your inputs etc...

Instead of counting your errors, here's how I'd do it... hopefully you'll find all the comments in the below example clear enough, but for further question feel free to ask so I can improve:

```js
// Let's say it does this...
var DocSignObj = {
  data: {
    sig: "sig_012345679abcd_sig" // Some digital signature
  },
  SignData: function(serializedForm) {
    this.data.serializedForm = serializedForm;
    return this.data;
  },
  _initialize: function(cb) {
    return cb(this.data);
  }
};

// Now...

function myCallbackFun(result) {
  // DIGITALLY SIGN BY API CALLBACK
  $("#DIG_SIG").val(result.sig);
}

function sign(form) {
  // does some stuff like serializing form data etc
  DocSignObj.SignData($(form).serialize());
  // presumably it checks if the "sig_***_sig"
  // from the serialized string is valid at submit-time.
}

function submitForm(event) {
  // 1 DON'T SUBMIT YET
  event.preventDefault();
  // 2 SIGN IT
  var signedData = sign(this); // where `this` is the $form
  // 3 SUBMIT FORM
  // $(this).submit();           // TODO: uncomment this line to submit form!
  console.log("SUBMITTED!!! %o", DocSignObj.data);
}

jQuery(function($) {
  //This lets the API know that SignData() function needs to call 
  //myCallbackFun function after its job is done
  DocSignObj._initialize(myCallbackFun);
  $("#FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED").on("submit", submitForm);
});
```

```html
<form id="FORM_TO_BE_SIGNED" action="" method="">
  <input name="sign" type="text" id="DIG_SIG" disabled> (the hidden one... just to test if SIG is being added)<br>
  <input name="data" type="text" id="data" value="Name Surname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Form Data">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: `DocSignObj.SignData` method does not return any thing . It just call `myCallbackFun` function which result as an argument

Comment: @JanardhanMaithil I suppose that clearly the sole purpose of `DocSignObj.SignData` is to check at submit-time if the serialized form data still contains the initial *valid* signature. I used `return` so I can test it in `console.log(signedData);` . You can remove that `return`.